# ¿Cómo leer y analizar un dataset en Pandas, para guardar los resultados usando Pickle?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

Hola tengo que hacer un tarea para un master ahora mismo tengo este codigo, me pueden decir si lo ven bien o si tengo algun fallo? mas dudas lo que tengo es en predict, que utilizará esta información guardada en la clase para transformar nuevos datos que le puedan llegar en formato DataFrame. En concreto este método deberá de retornar una versión modificada de este DataFrame en el que cada dato haya sido dividido por la media correspondiente a su columna. Se debe hacer con cuidado para no modificar los datos originales por lo que se recomienda hacer una copia profunda de los datos de entrada en una variable local del método. mi implantación es correcta?

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import copy

class NaiveModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loaded_median = None
        self.loaded_mean = None
        self.loaded_model = None

    def fit(self, df):
        """ Recibe un DataFrame externo y almacena la media de cada columna
            dentro de la clase en un diccionario."""
        self.result_mean = df.mean()

    def predict(self, df):
        """ Esta función crea una copia profunda del DataFrame y almacena los resultados
        de la media de cada columna en esta copia."""
        result_df = copy.deepcopy(df)
        for column in result_df.columns:
            result_df[column] /= self.result_mean[column]
        return result_df

    def save(self):
        """ Esta función toma los resultados de los métodos fit y predict anteriores y crea un Pickle de ellos. """
        with open('result_mean.pkl', 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(self.result_mean, file)

    def load(self):
        with open('result_mean.pkl', 'rb') as file:
            self.loaded_mean = pickle.load(file)
```

Comment: `df.copy()` realiza un deep copy, no es necesario llamar a la librería copy para ello. Lo otro, para save y load incorpora filename como argumento (puedes colocar este nombre por defecto), algo como: `def save(self, filename = 'result_mean.pkl'):` sino, no podrías modificar ese nombre una vez cargada la clase